# how to use R function in Java using toJava in rJava package

Tags: java, r

I have a long function written in R and I want to call this function in Java. Now I am using JRI to link R and Java. If I just use eval(XX), I can get the return from R in java environment. But because I have a long function, evaluating each line will be impractical. How can I use `toJava()` to generate a reference and how to use it in java?

I googled a example:enter code here

```
.jinit()
  # requires JRI and REngine classes
  .jengine(TRUE)
  f <- function() { cat("Hello!\n"); 1 }
  fref <- toJava(f)
  # to use this in Java you would use something like:



 # public static REXP call(REXPReference fn) throws REngineException, REXPMismatchException {
  #  return fn.getEngine().eval(new REXPLanguage(new RList(new REXP[] { fn })), null, false);
  # }
  # .jcall("Call","Lorg/rosuda/REngine/REXP;","call", fref)
```

I can create Fref in R environment, but how can I reference it in Java

For instance:
function  in R is : 
`f= function (){a=c(1,2,3); b=c(2,3,4); return (a+b)}` 
   how can I load this function in Java to calculate the result?

Comment: Are you trying to avoid using getEngine().eval? If you create that function in R as "fref", the example code works.

Comment: Thanks for your response! getEngine().eval just for one line right? but my function will have many lines, so if .eval for each line, it will be almost impossible. I used fref in R console, but after creating the object in r console, how can I use it in Java, see eclipse environment?

Comment: Np, and sorry, I don't know of a way to reference it like that via JRI. Perhaps you could just use a FileReader and run "eval" on each line? Or maybe try using something other than JRI, like [RCaller](https://code.google.com/p/rcaller/).